# Using Kivy Garden and Buildozer (in 2020): unable to deploy android app

Tags: python, android, kivy, virtualenv, buildozer

I am able to use Buildozer to deploy an android app only when Kivy Garden is not used. When I include the following line in the buildozer.spec file:

```
garden_requirements = graph
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

This is very strange to me as a newbie, because I am not even using a virtual environment and everything works fine without kivy garden (of course the app crashes, because it needs garden, but an apk file that crashes is built without errors).

Following recommendations from answers of questions asked in the past, I was able to install virtual environment and I **do** have a file in **venv/bin/activate** (again very strange to me). Activating the virtual environment and running buildozer after activating the environment gives the same error.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue (mapview instead of graph)

Comment: I have the same problem with ProgressSpinner, any solution?